# How can i make a response.write in the request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm

I'm creating HTTP server and inside i'm sending a request to to yahoo finance website and getting some data from it, what i want to do is to print to browser the data i got from yahoo finance.
the thing is that response.write isn't working inside the request.
Here is my code:

```
    var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var util = require('util');
var host  = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 1400;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //writing the headers of our response
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});

  // Variable Deceleration 
// TODO: move from the global scope
var ticker  = "IBM";
var yUrl    = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" + ticker;
var keyStr  = new Array();

//
// The main call to fetch the data, parse it and work on it.  
//
request(yUrl, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);


    // the keys - We get them from a certain class attribute
    var span = $('.time_rtq_ticker>span');
    stockValue = $(span).text();
    res.write("trying to print something");
    console.log("Stock  - " + ticker + " --> text " + stockValue );  
      }

}); // -- end of request --



    res.write('Welcome to StockWach\n');

  //printing out back to the client the last line
    res.end('end of demo');


});

server.listen(port, host, function () {
    console.log("Listening : " + host +":" + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to end the response (`res.end();`). Almost all browsers buffer some number of bytes from the response before showing anything, so you won't see the `trying to print something` until the response has ended.

If you use something like cURL though, you will see the `trying to print something` right away before the response is ended.

Comment: let's say that i'm also connecting to MySQL DB inside the request block, is it possible to pass stockValue value to the DB as an integer and not text?